# PHP - Store Multiple Values in Single Variable

Tags: php, variables

For example i have the PHP code like this

```
if ($rating_count == $rating_notnull) {
        $returnValue =  1;
    }
    if($project_count == $project_notnull) {
        $returnValue = 2;
    }
```

Now,I want to store two variable values into one single variable?

Comment: Why not use an array? A little more info would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays can be used to hold multiple values. They can have a key or not.

```
<?php

$x = array();

$x[] = 'Some Value';
$x[] = 'Another value';

var_dump($x);

$x = array();

$x['name'] = 'Anil';
$x['other name'] = 'Del Boy';

var_dump($x);

$x = array(
    'Name' => 'Batman',
    'Status' => 'Busy',
    'etc' => 'etc',
);

var_dump($x);
```

Have a play with it here: https://3v4l.org/LCjtY

Answer (score 0):

As explained in other comments the most efficient way would to be to use an array to store these values.

However, if you do wish to store this in a single variable you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

This will output it in an array when it is exploding however allows you to store it into one variable

```
$str = "Hello, this, is, a, variable";
explode(",", $str);
```